# Cannot read property 'event' of undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am implementing Persian DatePicker in WordPress Via Develope a Plugin

here is the libs of DatePicker:

http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/

but when i click on inspect in browser i see this error on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined
at persian-datepicker-0.4.5.min.js?ver=4.7.3:6
at persian-datepicker-0.4.5.min.js?ver=4.7.3:7
```

I also loads js libraries after JQuery Lib.

here is the code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//Datepicker
if ($('.em-date-single, .em-date-range, #em-date-start').length > 0) {
    em_setup_datepicker('body'); //Change class name to : .em-persian-date-start and .em-persian-date-end
    $('.em-persian-date-start').pDatepicker({
        persianDigit: true,
        viewMode: false,
        position: "auto",
        autoClose: false,
        format: false,
        observer: false,
        altField: '.em-date-input',
        inputDelay: 800,
        formatter: function (unixDate) {
            var self = this;
            var pdate = new persianDate(unixDate);
            pdate.formatPersian = false;
            return pdate.format(self.format);
        },
        altFormat: 'g',
        altFieldFormatter: function (unixDate) {
            var tzOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            var self = this;
            var thisAltFormat = self.altFormat.toLowerCase();
            if (thisAltFormat === "gregorian" | thisAltFormat === "g") {
                return new Date(unixDate - tzOffset).toISOString().substring(0, 10).replace('T', ' ');
            }
            if (thisAltFormat === "unix" | thisAltFormat === "u") {
                return unixDate;
            } else {
                return new persianDate(unixDate).format(self.altFormat);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (unixDate) {
            return this;
        },
        timePicker: {
            enabled: true,
            showSeconds: true,
            showMeridian: true,
            scrollEnabled: true
        },
        dayPicker: {
            enabled: true,
            scrollEnabled: true,
            titleFormat: 'YYYY MMMM',
            onSelect: function (selectedDayUnix) {
                setEndDate(selectedDayUnix);
            }

        },
        onlyTimePicker: false,
        justSelectOnDate: true,
        minDate: false,
        maxDate: false
    }); //init datePicker
}
});
```

Comment: Does `$('.em-persian-date-start').length` returns not 0?

Comment: Yes it returns 1 as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress we cannot use $, we must use 'jQuery' instead of '$'.

For example :

```
var len = jQuery('.classname').length;
```